# Two image hover effect css

Tags: html, css, image, hover, transition

I have two images one on top of another and have a neat looking transition when you hover with a mouse over it.

[Mouse hover image effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpAXS.jpg)

I have a problem though, I can't get my image to stick to inside my dotted box which I had created ([see my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/legaosijek/jerhtL26/latest/)) ...

If you can take a look at my fiddle it would explain my poor wordings...

As you can see in my example, I would like if my monitor could stay inside my dotted box. Currently, when you scroll down/or up monitor goes out of it ( underneath it.. )

Is it even possible to do with pure css without having background-position fixed ? if not, with what is?

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.w {
  border: dotted;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 261px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5) url("https://helpzona.com/testing/servicesHD.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&q=75&w=1920") repeat fixed;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 0;
}

.i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all 5.3s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5) url("https://helpzona.com/testing/servicesHD1.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&q=75&w=1920") repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.i:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0s linear;
  transition: all 0s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="w">
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="i"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get a faster response, it might help to include an image of the achieved effect, as well as putting your code examples right in the post using the tools that SO has available to do so. Good luck!

Comment: I added your code in a modified post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea using pseudo element and clip-path:

```css
.w {
  border: dotted;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 264px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: 
    rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5) url("https://helpzona.com/testing/servicesHD.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&q=75&w=1920") 
    top/auto 150% no-repeat; /* this should be the same as */
}

.i {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.i::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: 
    rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5) url("https://helpzona.com/testing/servicesHD1.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&q=75&w=1920") 
    top/auto 150% no-repeat; /* this! */
  transition: all 5.3s ease-in-out;
}

.i:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Temani! 

This is exactly what I wanted.